# Multiple instances of datepicker with onselect alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

There are many threads here for similar issues that I have read through and tried to apply to my situation being very new to all of this I haven't been able to figure it out I am afraid and was hoping for a little help

I need 2 instances of datepicker on my form with the javeascript alert if certain dates are selected. Using an example that i have found I am able to get one working but am unable name the other datepicker something unique in order to have the second one working as well

```
$(window).load(function(){
var Event = function (text, className) {
this.text = text;
this.className = className;
};

var events = {};
events[new Date("02/07/2014")] = new Event("Event01", "highlight");

events[new Date("02/26/2014")] = new Event("Event02", "highlight");
events[new Date("02/27/2014")] = new Event("Event03", "highlight");

$("#datepicker").datepicker({
beforeShowDay: function (date) {
    var event = events[date];
    if (event) {
        return [true, event.className, event.text];
    } else {
        return [true, '', ''];
    }
},
onSelect: function (date) {
    var event = events[new Date(date)];
    if (event) {
        alert(event.text)
    }
}
});
});//]]>  
</script>


<body>
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
<input type="text" id="datepicker2">

</body>
```

Any help gratefully received

Comment: Do both of your datepickers have the same ID? IDs must be unique.

Comment: thanks for the response I have tried 2 different data picker instances with different ID's and Class names to no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to apply the same functions to both datepickers then you would be better off assigning them a class and using that to control them.

`<input type="text" class="datepicker" />`

`$(".datepicker").datepicker({
beforeShowDay: function (date) {
    var event = events[date];
    if (event) {
        return [true, event.className, event.text];
    } else {
        return [true, '', ''];
    }
},
onSelect: function (date) {
    var event = events[new Date(date)];
    if (event) {
        alert(event.text)
    }
}
});`